# proof regarding zeta function of a curve from Ireland and Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory"

Tags: number-theory, projective-space, zeta-functions

In chapter $11$ section $5$ titled "the last entry" the authors state that the number of solutions to the congruence $x^2+y^2+x^2y^2 \equiv  1 \mod p$ is $p+1-2a$, where $p=a^2+b^2$ and $a+bi \equiv  1 \mod 2+2i.$

To prove this, they state another theorem:

> Consider the curve $C$ given by $x^2t^2+y^2t^2+x^2y^2-t^4$ over $F_p$ where 
>   $p \equiv  1 \mod 4$. Write $p=a^2+b^2$ with $a$ odd and $b$ even. if $4\mid b$, choose
>    $a\equiv 1\mod 4$; if $4\not\mid b$, choose $a\equiv -1\mod 4$. Then the number of points on $C$ in $P^2$ ($Fp$) is $p-1-2a.$

How does this second theorem relate to the first statement? It seems it's to prove the first one but I don't see how exactly. For instance, I don't see how the variable $t$ comes into play.

Comment: Use $\LaTeX{}$.

Comment: Dear animalcroc: perhaps you would like to add some detail in order to make the question self-contained?

Comment: @Bruno Joyal.  Request granted

Comment: Should one of those "$4\mid b$" be "$4\not\mid b$" instead? If so, use `$4\not\mid b$` to get that into the proper format.

Comment: A point $[x,y,t]$ on $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ with $t \neq 0$ corresponds bijectively to a solution $(x/t,y/t)$ to your given equation. There are 2 points on $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ when $t = 0$.

Comment: @CameronBuie.  fixed

Comment: @Sanchez  great answer, thanks. to clarify for others: take $x^2t^2+y^2t^2+x^2y^2-t^4=0$ and divide both sides by t^4. You then get a new equation $x'^2+y'^+x'^2y'^2-1=0$ where x'=x/t and y'=y/t

Comment: @Sanchez: Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868). Alternately, animalcroc could do so, as it is explicitly condoned for posters to answer their own questions whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $[x,y,t]$ on $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ with $t \neq 0$ corresponds bijectively to a solution $(x/t, y/t)$ to the given (dehomogenized) equation. There are 2 points on $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ when $t = 0$. This explains the difference of 2 in the point count of OP's question and the quoted theorem.

It does seem that OP may have a typo, where OP's question should have $p -1 - 2a$ points, and the quoted theorem should have $p+1-2a$ points.

Comment: perhaps someone corrected that typo if was there since I don't see it